# embed intagram feed on my magento site

Tags: magento, instagram

I have write the code to get the instagram image feed from json and its working fine here http://www.xesense.com/demo/instagram/

```
 <style>
.instagram-wrap {
float: left;
width: 16.6666%;
}

.instagram-wrap img.instagram-image {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";     
//*** YOU NEED TO GET YOUR OWN ACCESS TOKEN FROM INSTAGRAM
var resolution = "thumbnail"; 
var user_id = "XXXXXXX";
var hashtag = "XXXXXX";
var last_url = "";

var start_url =    "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+user_id+"/media/recent/?    access_token="+access_token;
 function loadEmUp(next_url){
 url = next_url;

  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: url ,
            success: function(data) {

            next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
            count = 18;  
                        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (typeof data.data[i] !== 'undefined' ) {
                        $("#instagram").append("<div class='instagram-wrap' id='pic-"+ data.data[i].id +"' ><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>"
                    );  
                    }  
            }     
        }
      });
       });
     }
    //CALL THE SCRIPT TO START...
   jQuery(function($) {
    loadEmUp(start_url);
    });
    </script>

    <div id="instagram"></div>
```

But when i add this code in magento static block its not working here
https://naturerestore.com/
i have created the core template file with name of intagram/instagram.phtml
i thought this is due to the conflict error.

Comment: I'm new in Magento, I want to implement this on homepage in Magento 2.1, Can anyone please guide me that where I place this code...

Comment: HI Waqas
Create and custom template like `code`this app/design/frontend/you-theme/template/page/instagram/instagram.phtml
then call this template like this
<block type="core/instagram" name="instagram" as="instagram" template="page/instagram/instagram.phtml" />

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try to implement it like this...

Comment: Why don't you try https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html and make your instagram shoppable.

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are not intended to keep the code. You can better add phtml template file and either call it in home page like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="home_instagram" template="instagram/instagram.phtml"}}
```

Or you can add your block in xml file of the theme like this:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
         <block type="core/template" after="-" name="home_instagram" template="instagram/instagram.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

That way it will be outputted automatically on home page. Just keep in mind that you can add `before` instead of `after` that I used in demo. `after="-"` means to be outputted after all elements on the page.

Comment: Hi, i have used same method {{block type="core/template" name="home_instagram" template="instagram/instagram.phtml"}} to calling the core template file. but seems not working.
no output is giving right now

Comment: I'm new in Magento, I want to implement this on homepage in Magento 2.1, Can anyone please guide me that where I place this code...

Answer (score 0):

You can make a template file for this in `page/template/instagram.phtml` and create block in page.xml by

```
<block type="core/template" name="instagram" as="instagram" template="page/template/instagram.phtml" />
```

And call your block in template file by  `echo $this->getChildHtml('instagram')`

Hope your instagram feeds code is working fine

this will helps you,

Comment: I'm new in Magento, I want to implement this on homepage in Magento 2.1, Can anyone please guide me that where I place this code...